# How to exit a "virsh console" connection?

Tags: linux-kvm, virtual-console, virsh

Is there any special characters involved? I want to be able to open a console connection in my application and exit upon completion of a task

Answer (score 56, accepted):

To get out from a `virsh` console (with a standard English keyboard) try:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>

or

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>

All those special keys are quite a problem when using keyboards other than a standard English one.

For example on a Swedish keyboard the combination would be:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>å</kbd>

Comment: Something has definitely been lost in the translation of the second part of your answer.

Answer (score 9):

- Danish keyboard:

  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>^¨~</kbd>
- English keyboard:

  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>
  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>
- French keyboard:

  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>
  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>$€*</kbd> (OS X)
- German keyboard:

  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>
  - <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>
  - <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> (Mac)
- Norwegian keyboard:

  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>^¨~</kbd>
- Swedish keyboard:

  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>å</kbd> (OS X)

---

- [Brettetete](https://superuser.com/users/316511/brettetete)

  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>

Comment: Are there any other known key combinations? I have Slovenian keyboard and I tried all of the above options (same position and same keys) and none of them work.

Comment: For me - German Keyboard, Ubuntu Linux, the solutions with "ctrl-shift-5" or "strg-shift-5" dont work.
What's working is the solution decsribed as it's for Mac: "ctrl-alt-5" or "Strg-alt-5" (STrg" is just the German label for the control key, they are the same keys.

Answer (score 2):

Norwegian keyboard; CTRL + "^¨~" button

Comment: The Danish keyboard sequence is the same as the Norwegian one: CTRL + "^¨~" button

Comment: This worked on a swedish keyboard

Answer (score 0):

With german keyboard Ctrl+5 worked. (Strg+5)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>

worked for me. all the other solutions in here didn't

Answer (score 0):

With French keyboard, OS X: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>$</kbd>. 
(On the Apple wireless French keyboard, `$`, `€`, and `*`
are on a key to the left of the Enter key.)  See this picture:

[image: the Apple wireless French keyboard]

Comment: Is that the same as (Ctrl)+(Shift)+(4)?

Comment: nope, on my keyboard (apple wireless french keyboard) it is on the left of the enter key. see this picture : http://ilovemymac.bachibouzouks.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/HT1171_01-wireless_keyboard-001-fr.png

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for those who have problems finding the shortcut:

1. Change your systems keyboard language to a U.S Keyboard language
2. Look at an image of a US keyboard layout and ctrl+] the corresponding keys on your keyboard

Answer (score 0):

MacBookPro with Swiss German layout: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>¨</kbd> ("under" the <kbd>!</kbd>, to the left of <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Answer (score -1):

On German **Mac** Keyboard:  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>

Comment: The [community wiki](http://superuser.com/a/1030068/393570) post suggests that it is actually `ctrl` + `shift` + `5`. Have you got any documentation to back this up?

Comment: there is a difference between German **PC** keyboard layout and German **Mac** keyboard layout. The suggested one is for PC, not Mac. I back this up through daily practice.

Comment: @Burgi community wiki answer just summed up other answers here, but IMVHO Fadi Asbih should just extend community wiki answer...

Answer (score -2):

On a French keyboard, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> works great.